# How to perform cross validation clustered input data?

Tags: r, clustering, cross-validation

How do i perform knn cross validation with input data that has been clustered using k-means.

I seem to be unable to find the correct function which is able to do so.

`predict.strengt` from `fpc`seem to be able to compute some form of prediction rate given a classifier method, but it seems it test it against the training set, which in my mind doesn't seem that beneficial.

Aren't there any function which can perform cross validation?

Comment: knn or kmeans? it's not the same. Also, if you google for clustering and cross-validation, you will find that this is not appropriate. You need labels for CV, and you don't useclustering if you already have labels.

Comment: thanks for the response.. 
So the idea is that i have clustered my data using k-means, into 50 clusters.

Comment: I am not sure i understand your point.. 
I am using the clustering as method to reduce the dimensionality of my data set, such that i don't need to provided the raw data, but just learns based on the clusters. So I want to perform knn using the clustered dataset.

Comment: What do you get with kNN on the centroids? The centroids have little meaning. They are just points.

Comment: But how does the function `predict.strength` utilize it?

Comment: I don't know. I've looked at fpc once, and it was horribly slow, so I uninstalled it again IIRC.

Comment: The method seem to be an implementation of https://statistics.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/2001-21.pdf